# ACL rules for web application

Tags: access-control-list

When setting up an EC2 instance for my website, I found this warning by AWS:

> Improve your instances' security. Your security group,
>   example-group-1, is open to the world.

In the relevant section, I had set three rules:

```
Type:SSH   Protocol:TCP Port:22  Source: 0.0.0.0/0
Type:HTTP  Protocol:TCP Port:80  Source: 0.0.0.0/0
Type:HTTPS Protocol:TCP Port:443 Source: 0.0.0.0/0
```

Since this web application is supposed to get traffic from outside, aren't these rules fine? The warning is making me paranoid whether I'm missing something. Would be great to get an expert's opinion on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to allow consciously anybody in the world to reach `SSH`, `HTTP` and `HTTPS` on your server, then you are fine and you can safely ignore this warning, knowing what your are doing.

By the way, except if your Web App really need it, `SSH` seems to be more for remote server administration.
If this is the case you should restrict this to your own IP.

Comment: My own IP is dynamic, so it's subject to change. What's best practice in that case?

Comment: Do you connect to `ssh` using password ? If so, i would recommand the key pair method (private/public) using the private key provided by Amazon for your EC2 instance, and keep this private key in a safe place. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstances.html

Comment: Yes, I use the key, not a password.